# How do I change payment currency on American Airlines

Tags: air-travel, tickets, payment-cards

I was trying to book a flight on American Airlines using my American credit card paying in dollars. However, the website insists on showing me the prices in pounds and I can't switch my residence country from the UK (where I am now) to the US.
Is there a way to change it?

Comment: So far I figured out one way: Use American VPN + guest account!

Comment: Most airlines show prices and charge using the currency of the country where the flight originates (the first flight for return or multi-city itineraries). I’m surprised AA do it differently.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re browsing americanairlines.co.uk. If you switch your region to the USA it’ll show you dollars instead.
[image]
The region selection menu is in the upper right corner. It may not be visible if you’re already searching flights, but will be visible if you return to the home page.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.